# typeorm vs mongoose with graphql which one to choose and why?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, typeorm

I am bit confuse right now, I am new to graphql and now I have seen some people use mongodb with mongoose and others use with typeorm, I dont know which one is better to use with nodejs, typescript, graphql, mongodb.

can anyone guide me on this please?